# openssl_dh_compute_key returns false

Tags: php, diffie-hellman, php-openssl

I'm trying to compute the shared secret for ECDH (Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman) using PHP.

Assume I have someone's public key.
$clientPublickey = "BOLcHOg4ajSHR6BjbSBeX_6aXjMu1V5RrUYXqyV_FqtQSd8RzdU1gkMv1DlRPDIUtFK6Nd16Jql0eSzyZh4V2uc";

I generate my keys using OpenSSL.

```
exec('openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out example-ecc.pem');
$private = openssl_pkey_get_private("file://example-ecc.pem");
```

Using the following code, I get `false` as value for `$sharedSecret`.

```
$sharedSecret = openssl_dh_compute_key(base64_decode($clientPublickey), $private);
```

`openssl_error_string()` doesn't return any error.

I've var_dumped `openssl_pkey_get_details($private)` and I verified it was created properly.

How do I use [`openssl_dh_compute_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-dh-compute-key.php)?

Comment: I have a feeling that the function does not support EC keys, only RSA ..

Answer (score 3):

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/DH_compute_key.html describes that function as being for (non-EC) Diffie Hellman.  You would need `ECDH_compute_key` (which I don't know if PHP exposes).

Though https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie_Hellman recommends using the EVP_PKEY wrappers instead of the low level routines. But, again, I can't say what support PHP has.

Answer (score 1):

[`openssl_dh_compute_key()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-dh-compute-key.php) supports ECDH only in PHP 8.1.0, with OpenSSL 3.0.0. Before PHP 8.1.0, `openssl_dh_compute_key()` always returned `false`.

Starting from PHP 7.3, there is [`openssl_pkey_derive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-derive.php) which derives a shared secret from a set of public key and private key. It works either with DH or EC keys. The example code given for this function is simpler than the example given for `openssl_dh_compute_key()`, which generate a public/private DH keypair using the command line.

```php
$private = openssl_pkey_get_private("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
");

$public = openssl_pkey_get_public("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
");

echo bin2hex(openssl_pkey_derive($public, $private));
```

For other PHP 7 releases, there are pure PHP implementations like [phpecc/phpecc](https://github.com/phpecc/phpecc), which can generate a shared encryption key using [code similar to the following one](https://github.com/phpecc/phpecc/blob/master/examples/ecdh_exchange.php). (It's one of the library examples.)

```php
use Mdanter\Ecc\EccFactory;
use Mdanter\Ecc\Primitives\GeneratorPoint;
use Mdanter\Ecc\Serializer\PrivateKey\PemPrivateKeySerializer;
use Mdanter\Ecc\Serializer\PrivateKey\DerPrivateKeySerializer;
use Mdanter\Ecc\Serializer\PublicKey\DerPublicKeySerializer;
use Mdanter\Ecc\Serializer\PublicKey\PemPublicKeySerializer;
use Mdanter\Ecc\Util\NumberSize;

// ECDSA domain is defined by curve/generator/hash algorithm,
// which a verifier must be aware of.

$adapter = EccFactory::getAdapter();
$generator = EccFactory::getNistCurves()->generator384();
$useDerandomizedSignatures = true;

$derPub = new DerPublicKeySerializer();
$pemPub = new PemPublicKeySerializer($derPub);
$pemPriv = new PemPrivateKeySerializer(new DerPrivateKeySerializer($adapter, $derPub));

# These .pem and .key are for different keys
$alicePriv = $pemPriv->parse(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../tests/data/openssl-secp256r1.pem'));
$bobPub = $pemPub->parse(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../tests/data/openssl-secp256r1.1.pub.pem'));

$exchange = $alicePriv->createExchange($bobPub);
$shared = $exchange->calculateSharedKey();
echo "Shared secret: " . gmp_strval($shared, 10).PHP_EOL;

# The shared key is never used directly, but used with a key derivation function (KDF)
$kdf = function (GeneratorPoint $G, \GMP $sharedSecret) {
    $adapter = $G->getAdapter();
    $binary = $adapter->intToFixedSizeString(
        $sharedSecret,
        NumberSize::bnNumBytes($adapter, $G->getOrder())
    );

    $hash = hash('sha256', $binary, true);
    return $hash;
};

$key = $kdf($generator, $shared);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old post, but still..

I think your public key is not formatted in Base64, but in URL-safe-Base64.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications

Furthermore, you can create the keys also from PHP now. Using `openssl_pkey_new()`.
See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php